# RuntimeException on android app with parse.com push notification

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification

I've followed this  [Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications) at parse.com but
when I've added   `subscribeInBackground` method to `OnCreate` I get a RuntimeException

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParsePush;
import com.parse.PushService;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
    Parse.initialize(this, "mykey", "anotherkey");
   ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
            } else {
                Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and the manifest it's

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.me.myapplication" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.example.me.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.me.myapplication.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</application>
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

        <!--
          IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.tutorials.pushnotifications" to match your app's package name.
        -->
        <category android:name="com.example.me.myapplication" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the error log it's

```
Process: com.example.me.myapplication, PID: 19694
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.me.myapplication/com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
(Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
(Replace "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" with your own implementation if you choose to extend ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)
        at com.parse.ParsePush.checkForManifestAndThrowExceptionIfNeeded(ParsePush.java:152)
        at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:78)
        at com.parse.ParsePush.subscribeInBackground(ParsePush.java:99)
        at com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
```

Comment: Your link points to w3schools.com, and not parse.com.

Comment: now ponts to parse.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the exception it is self explanatory:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: In order to use the ParsePush.subscribe or ParsePush.unsubscribe methods you must add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml:
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**EDIT:**

you have closed the application tag way to early. that needs to be at the bottom, the services and the receivers must be included in the application, close the application tag after them.

Comment: then why do you still get that exception? have you posted an older stack trace or the exception keeps reoccurring despite that you have added the receiver in the manifest?

Comment: now I see it, you have closed the application tag (</application>) way to early. that needs to be at the bottom, the services and the receivers must be included in the application, close the </application> after them.